# Dymanic content in Flash as3 video - take this lollipop clone

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, dynamic

I'm in a project where I need to create a dynamic video like the famous "take this lollipop" where some content are dynamically added to the vídeo ,but I don't have enough experience with as3(I'm a js developer).

Take this screenshot of the video as an example, I need to simulate an facebook page with some dynamic content in it.

http://imgur.com/XHc7XSL

What i'm thinking of doing is create a Movieclip with all the content and insert into the stage on top of the phone screen and on each frame change the position of the MovieClip, which must be distorted, to match the phone screen.

All I want to know from experienced as3 developers is if that is the better solution or there is another way of doing it as this method require al ot of manual work to match the coordinates of the phone screen.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I got was from Colin Holgate at Adobe forum.

> In an AS3 FLA you can place a bitmap into a movieclip and then 3D
>   rotate/distort the image. Put the rotated movieclip in front of the
>   phone screen. You could even animate it to keep up with a moving
>   phone.   Now, the tricky party is making the two things be exactly in
>   sync, and anything like this that I've seen online was achieved that
>   by importing the video into the Flash time line, instead of playing an
>   external video file.